# Check if URLquery match

Tags: php

I have a URL query within `get.php?&uniId=2` I have code that checks if url string is present.

However my if statement dose not seem to be working correctly

```
   <?php

if(empty($_GET {"uniId=3"})) {
    echo "you are able to accsess this page !";

    var_dump($_REQUEST);

} else {
    echo "sorry no access for you";
}
```

if i type in http://localhost/mysite/get.php?&uniId=3

I get

```
echo "you are able to accsess this page !";
```

and if i type in http://localhost/mysite/get.php?&uniId=2

I get

`echo "you are able to accsess this page !";`

not

```
echo "sorry no access for you";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the key exist first and than, check the value :

i.e. :

```
//check if the key exists
if(!empty($_GET{"uniId"})) {
    // check if the value = 3
    if ($_GET{"uniId"} == 3) {
        // do stuff if result is true
    } else {
        // do stuff if result is false
    }
} else {
    echo "The key \"uniId\" does not exists";
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Glad it helps you. Please, click on the green tic below the vote counter if this answer solves your question.